# Backup core data locally, and restore from backup - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, backup, restore

I'm struggling to find any information about creating backups of core data. My ultimate goal is to allow the user to create multiple backups, and restore from a selected backup.

I've found a sample project that allows you backup/restore locally or via iCloud in Objective-C, but nothing in swift.

Can anyone help? Or point me in the right direction. I don't even know where to start with this one.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I've never needed to do this but if I did this is what I'd do.

### To make backups

At any time, use the following steps:

1. Create a new, second Core Data stack. Use either `NSPersistentContainer` or the older (but still supported) method of creating an `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`.
2. Use `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`'s function `migratePersistentStore(_:to:options:withType:)` to create the backup. Make the destination URL include something unique, using a UUID or a timestamp. Put the backups in the documents folder.
3. Keep a list of backups by date. You could put this in `UserDefaults` or create a new property list file to save backup info.

Step #2 will remove the original store from the Core Data stack-- which is why you create a second stack in step #1. This way you can use the second stack to make the backup without affecting the one your app is using.

If you're using `NSPersistentContainer`, use its `persistentStoreCoordinator` property to carry out step #2.

### To restore from backups

This is a little bit tricky because your app may be using its persistent store, but now you want to replace that with an older version. **Before restoring from a backup, make sure you're not currently using any managed objects from the persistent store.** Deallocate your `NSPersistentContainer`. Unload any UI that makes use of managed objects. Get your app into a state where all it can do is either restore from a backup or go back to using the current data, but where it's not showing any data except the backup list.

Now that you've done that,

1. Display the backup list and let the user select one.
2. Create an `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator` using your data model.
3. Use the `replacePersistentStore(at:destinationOptions:withPersistentStoreFrom:sourceOptions:ofType:)` method to copy the backup data to the normal app location. The starting location is the backup location, the destination is where the app normally saves its data.
4. (optional) Use `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`'s function `destroyPersistentStore(at:ofType:options:)` to delete the backup.
5. Load an `NSPersistentContainer` as usual and reload the regular app UI.

Don't use direct file-related APIs like `FileManager` for any of this. The Core Data methods will cover all of the Core Data-related files and do other nice things like avoid causing data corruption and respecting file locks.

**Update**: I later wrote a blog post that covers this in more detail, with sample code: https://atomicbird.com/blog/core-data-back-up-store/

Comment: I wonder... has anyone tried this using large data attributes stored using the "Allows External Storage" option?

Comment: It should just work, same as with any other data model.

Comment: Ole Begemann wrote an implementation based on this solution here: https://oleb.net/blog/2018/03/core-data-sqlite-backup/, and clarified that it does work with the "Allows External Storage" option.

Comment: Can this directly migrate .xcdatamodel to icloud url?

Answer (score 11):

### Details

- Swift 5.1, Xcode 11.3.1

### Core-Data Backup

```
 func backup(backupName: String){
        let backUpFolderUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in:.userDomainMask).first!
        let backupUrl = backUpFolderUrl.appendingPathComponent(backupName + ".sqlite")
        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "Your Project Name")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in })

        let store:NSPersistentStore
        store = container.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.last!
        do {
            try container.persistentStoreCoordinator.migratePersistentStore(store,to: backupUrl,options: nil,withType: NSSQLiteStoreType)
        } catch {
            print("Failed to migrate")
        }
    }
```

That's it!

Now,

### Core-Data Restore

```
func restoreFromStore(backupName: String){

        print(DatabaseHelper.shareInstance.getAllUsers())
        let storeFolderUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in:.userDomainMask).first!
        let storeUrl = storeFolderUrl.appendingPathComponent("YourProjectName.sqlite")
        let backUpFolderUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in:.userDomainMask).first!
        let backupUrl = backUpFolderUrl.appendingPathComponent(backupName + ".sqlite")

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "YourProjectName")
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in
            let stores = container.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores

            for store in stores {
                print(store)
                print(container)
            }
            do{
                try container.persistentStoreCoordinator.replacePersistentStore(at: storeUrl,destinationOptions: nil,withPersistentStoreFrom: backupUrl,sourceOptions: nil,ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType)
                print(DatabaseHelper.shareInstance.getAllUsers())
            } catch {
                print("Failed to restore")
            }

        })

    }
```

### Usage

```
self.backup(backupName: "first_backup")
self.restoreFromStore(backupName: "first_backup")
```

That's it.. Hope this helpful. Thank You

Comment: Can you please add some comments in your code and explain the purpose of important steps? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Just my two cents for more valuable thoughts: to tackle the problem, I would try to use CloudKit to create different customer zones to store different backups in the App user’s private database in iCloud from core data.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. It’s important to my app that this process is completely offline and not reliant on CloudKit or iCloud. So I really need to store locally. I believe it’s just a case of copying the sql lite file and saving to location. To restore. Copy back. But I’ve no idea how to do this.

Comment: I have no experience with offline backup but would research encoding data to local file and compressing the file to indirectly serve your purpose and using Swift. To directly backup and restore SQL Lite file, I would look into standard library but doubt about any findings of Swift implementation.  If you find sth, please share with me.

Answer (score 0):

I created the following method with the help of Tom's answer and the Apple sample [code](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/PersistentStoreFeatures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH23-SW1).
This will take a backup of core data files and place it to the path that you want.

> Swift 5

```
    /// Backing up store type to a new and unique location
    /// The method is illustrated in the following code fragment, which shows how you can use migratePersistentStore to take a back up of a store and save it from one location to another.
    /// If the old store type is XML, the example also converts the store to SQLite.
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - path: Where you want the backup to be done, please create a new unique directory with timestamp or the guid
    ///   - completion: Passes error in case of error or pass nil in case of success
     class func backUpCoreDataFiles(path : URL, completion : @escaping (_ error : String?) -> ())
        {

            // Every time new container is a must as migratePersistentStore method will loose the reference to the container on migration
            let container = NSPersistentContainer(name : "<YourDataModelName>")
            container.loadPersistentStores
                { (storeDescription, error) in
                    if let error = error
                    {
                        fatalError("Failed to load store: \(error)")
                    }
            }
            let coordinator = container.persistentStoreCoordinator
            let store = coordinator.persistentStores[0]
            do
            {
                try coordinator.migratePersistentStore(store, to : path, options : nil, withType : NSSQLiteStoreType)
                completion(nil)
            }
            catch
            {
                completion("\(Errors.coredataBackupError)\(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        }
```

Comment: I had a requirement of taking a snapshot of the coredata stack, zip it, password protect it and upload to the azure as a blob, this blob is preserved with timestamp and user can track back to that snapshot of data stack anytime he wishes.

Comment: what should be the path? I mean should I pass like documentsDir+"backup.sqlite" ??

Comment: Yes the path should have .sqlite added to it

Comment: Hii, not finding Errors in catch block ?

Comment: facing this error Failed to load model named? please help thanks