# Restore Core Data

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspersistentstore

I've managed to create a local backup of my PersistentStore using the following code:

```
func backup(){
    let backUpFolderUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in:.userDomainMask).first!
    let backupUrl = backUpFolderUrl.appendingPathComponent("backup")
    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyApp")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in })

    let store:NSPersistentStore
    store = container.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.last!
    do {
        try container.persistentStoreCoordinator.migratePersistentStore(store,
                                                                        to: backupUrl,
                                                                        options: nil,
                                                                        withType: NSSQLiteStoreType)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to migrate")
    }
}
```

This seems to work. The backup files are created. This answer:
[Backup core data locally, and restore from backup - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48613271/backup-core-data-locally-and-restore-from-backup-swift)
Suggests I need to deallocate my NSPersistentContainer and then use replacePersistentStore(at:destinationOptions:withPersistentStoreFrom:sourceOptions:ofType:) to restore my backup. So I tried like this:

```
func restoreFromStore(){
    let storeFolderUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .applicationSupportDirectory, in:.userDomainMask).first!
    let storeUrl = storeFolderUrl.appendingPathComponent("MyApp")
    let backUpFolderUrl = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in:.userDomainMask).first!
    let backupUrl = backUpFolderUrl.appendingPathComponent("backup")

    let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MyApp")
    container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in })

    let stores = container.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores

    for store in stores {
        do {
            try container.deall
        } catch {
            print("Couldnt clear store")
        }
    }

    do{
        try
            container.persistentStoreCoordinator.replacePersistentStore(at: storeUrl,
                                                                        destinationOptions: nil,
                                                                        withPersistentStoreFrom: backupUrl,
                                                                        sourceOptions: nil,
                                                                        ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType)
    } catch {
        print("Failed to restore")
    }
}
```

This doesn’t seem to do anything. I don’t get any errors or warnings but it also doesn’t seem to restore my core data at the point I backed it up.

Sorry, I know this is probably awful code. I actually achieved the result I wanted using entirely FileManager but it seemed to make my console really angry. I wanted to do it properly, without any warnings.

Comment: What specifically is not working?

Comment: @TomHarrington  thanks for the response. It just doesn’t restore my original core data stack. For example. I create some core data. Run backup. Then change the data. Run restore. It doesn’t do anything. No errors. But also doesn’t restore to before changes were made. The backup appears to be working. Files are created in backup directory.

Comment: Hi,  try your code for backup and restore. i am not getting any error but how can i found my entity ? THanks

Comment: If possible then can you please add your final working code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s hard to be certain, but a likely cause is

- `loadPersistentStores` is an async operation, which is why it has a completion block
- You’re attempting to restore immediately after calling that method instead of waiting for it to finish.

You probably need to move your restore code inside the completion block that `loadPersistentStores` uses, so that you can be sure the loading has finished.

Comment: Again! you were absolutely right. Ran through the above steps separately and it works a treat. It just needs some completion handlers in there! Thanks again.

Comment: I think I'm having the same issue.  Could you post your final code here that worked so I can check mine.  Thanks.