# How to create snapshot of CoreData state?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data

#### Background story

I am developing a big iOS app. This app works under specific assumptions. The main of them is that app should work offline with internal storage which is a snapshot of last synchronized state of data saved on server. I decided to use CoreData to handle this storage. Every time app launches I check if WiFi connection is enabled and then try to synchronize storage with server. The synchronization can take about 3 minutes because of size of data.

The synchronization process consists of several stages and in each of them I:

- fetch some data from the server (XML)
- deserialize it
- save it in Core Data

#### Problem

Synchronization process can be interrupted for several reasons (internet connection, server down, user leaving application, etc). This may cause data to be out-of-sync.

Let's assume that synchronization process has 5 stages and it breaks after third. It results in 3/5 of data being updated in internal storage and the rest being out of sync. I can't allow it because data are strongly connected to each other (business logic).

#### Goal

I don't know if it is possible but I'm thinking about implementing one solution. On start of synchronization process I would like to create snapshot (some kind of copy) of current state of Core Date and during synchronization process work on it. When synchronization process completes with success then this snapshot could overwrite current CoreData state. When synchronization interrupts then snapshot can be simply aborted. My internal storage will be secured.

#### Questions

- How to create CoreData snapshot?
- How to work with CoreData snapshot?
- How to overwrite CoreDate state with snapshot?

Thanks in advice for any help. Code examples, if it is possible, will be appreciated.

#### EDIT 1

The size of data is too big to handle it with multiple CoreData's contexts. During synchronization I am saving current context multiple times to cleanup memory. If I do not do it, the application will crash with memory error.

I think it should be resolved with multiple `NSPersistentStoreCoordinator`s using for example this method: [link](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coredata/nspersistentstorecoordinator/1468917-replacepersistentstore). Unfortunately, I don't know how to implement this.

Comment: https://oleb.net/blog/2018/03/core-data-sqlite-backup/

Comment: Thanks @canister_exister but it covers only part of my problem. :)

Comment: Can you create a managed object context for your sync? You can commit the changes if everything completes successfully, or call `rollback()` if they don't?

Comment: @AaronBrager Thanks for response. I edited my question.

Comment: Do you think this question / answer might be of help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50647579/core-data-how-to-swap-nspersistentstores-and-inform-nsfetchedresultscontroller You can back up your current store, start a new one, and if syncing from the server fails, you can revert to your old one using the `replacePersistentStore(...)` method you described.

Comment: So if 99% of the data has been downloaded and handled when an interruption of some sort occurs you want to throw those 99% away and start over the next time?

Answer (score 0):

You should do exactly what you said. Just create class (lets call it SyncBuffer) with methods "load", "sync" and "save".

The "load" method should read all entities from CoreData and store it in class variables.
The "sync" method should make all the synchronisation using class variables.
Finally the "save" method should save all values from class variables to CoreData - here you can even remove all data from CoreData and save brand new values from SyncBuffer.

Comment: Thanks for response. I edited my question. Unfortunately, keeping data in memory will crash application.

Comment: This synchronisation is working two ways or you are just synchronising data from server to your app?

During synchronisation are you comparing whole objects or just some ids?

It will be really good to have more background about your app.

Comment: One way. Server -> App. Synchronization overrides models with the same ID.

Answer (score 0):

A CoreData stack is composed at its core by three components: A context (NSManagedObjectContext) a model (NSManagedObjectModel) and the store coordinator (NSPersistentStoreCoordinator/NSPersistentStore).

What you want is to have **two different contexts**, that shares **the same model** but use **two different stores**. The store itself will be of the same type (i.e. an SQLite db) but use a different source file.

At this page you can see some documentation about the stack:

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/InitializingtheCoreDataStack.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001075-CH4-SW1

The NSPersistentContainer is a convenience class to initialise the CoreData stack.

Take the example of the initialisation of a NSPersistentContainer from the link: you can have the exact same code to initialise it, **twice**, but with the only difference that the two NSPersistentContainer use **a different .sqlite file**: i.e. you can have two properties in your app delegate called managedObjectContextForUI and managedObjectContextForSyncing that loads different .sqlite files. Then in your program you can use the context from one store to get current data to show to the user and you can use the context that use **the other store** with a different .sqlite if you are doing sync operations. When the sync operations are finally done you can eventually swap the two files and after clearing and reloading the NSPersistentContainer (this might be tricky, because you will want to invalidate and reload all managed objects: you are switching to an entirely new context) you can then show the newly synced data to the user **and start syncing again on a new .sqlite file**.

Answer (score 0):

The way I understand the problem is that you wish to be able download a large "object graph". It is however so large that it cannot be loaded at once in memory, so you would have to break it in chunks and then merge it locally into to Core data.

If that is the case, I think that's not trivial. I am not sure I can think of direct solution without understanding the object relations and even then it may be really overwhelming.

An overly simplistic solution may be to generate the sqlite file on the backend then download it in chunks; it seems ugly, but it serves to separate the business logic from the sync, i.e. the sqlite file becomes the transport layer. So, I think the essence to the solution would be to find a way to physically represent the data you are syncing in a format that allows for splitting it in chunks and that can afterwards be merged into a sqlite file (if you insist on using Core data).

Please also note that as far as I know Amazon (https://aws.amazon.com/appsync/) and Realm (https://realm.io/blog/introducing-realm-mobile-platform/) provide background sync of you local database, but those are paid services and you would have to be careful not be locked in (should not depend on their libs in your model layer, instead have a translation layer).