# How to delete PersistentStore and recreate it to add new data?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, nspersistentstore

I use a CoreData database in my app. I need to delete it (model and all data) and recreate it when the app is updated.

To delete it, I use `destroyPersistentStore` function.
But after deleting, I need to recreate the `persistentStores`, to fill it with new data.

Here my `CoreDataManager` class:

```
class CoreDataManager {

    static let sharedManager = CoreDataManager()
    private init() {}

    lazy var persistentContainer: NSPersistentContainer = {

        let container = NSPersistentContainer(name: storeName)
        container.loadPersistentStores(completionHandler: { (storeDescription, error) in

            if let error = error as NSError? {
                fatalError("Unresolved error \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
            }
        })
        return container
    }()

   func resetCoreData(){

        guard let firstStoreURL = self.persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.persistentStores.first?.url else {
            print("Missing first store URL - could not destroy")
            return
        }

        do {
            try self.persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.destroyPersistentStore(at: firstStoreURL, ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, options: nil)
        } catch  {
            print("Unable to destroy persistent store: \(error) - \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }
   }

 func recreateCoreData() {
        do {
             try self.persistentContainer.persistentStoreCoordinator.addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: storeName, at: firstStoreURL, options: nil)
         } catch {
             print("Unable to create persistent store: \(error) - \(error.localizedDescription)")
         }
  }
}
```

I have an error with my `recreateCoreData` call because the store is incompatible with the one used when it was created.

What's wrong?

EDIT:

The database model didn't change between 2 versions.

The error:

```
Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=134020 "The model configuration used to open the store is incompatible with the one that was used to create the store."
```

Comment: If your CoreData model changes between app version you’ll likely need to perform a migration.

Comment: My model didn't change between the 2 versions.

Comment: Please post the error that tells you the data stores are incompatible.

Comment: @Magnas I edited my question

Comment: Have you tried using the `persistentStoreCoordinator.replacePersistentStore` on the persistentContainer? I used it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50647579/core-data-how-to-swap-nspersistentstores-and-inform-nsfetchedresultscontroller/50682039#50682039 for a similar (but not exactly the same) delete/restore scenario. Also, if your model doesn't change between app versions can I ask why you don't simply delete all objects from the store and keep everything else for the new version?

Comment: The error indicates that the problem is with the model *configuration*.  You are using storeName as the configurationName in the recreateCoreData method.  Are you sure that’s what you want to do?  Or should you be using nil?

Answer (score 4):

This probably happens because of the parameter `configurationName` when calling `addPersistentStore`:

```
addPersistentStore(ofType: NSSQLiteStoreType, configurationName: storeName, ...)
```

The configuration name is not the store name, if you dump it from the existing store, you get `PF_DEFAULT_CONFIGURATION_NAME` as result.

You could use this from the existing store (`firstStore.configurationName`), or imho a bit easier, by calling `persistentContainer.loadPersistentStores(...)` again.

Example project: https://github.com/ralfebert/CoreDataReset