# Backup core data, one entity only

Tags: json, swift, core-data

My application requires some kind of data backup and some kind of data exchange between users, so what I want to achieve is the ability to export an entity but not the entire database.

I have found some help but for the full database, like this post:

[Backup core data locally, and restore from backup - Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48613271/backup-core-data-locally-and-restore-from-backup-swift)

This applies to the entire database.

I tried to export a JSON file, this might work except that the entity I'm trying to export contains images as binary data.

So I'm stuck.

Any help exporting not the full database but just  one entity or how to write a JSON that includes binary data.

Comment: You could encode files (images, etc.) into Data and then into Base64 string that you could put inside a JSON, but that's some JSON in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at protobuf. Apple has an official swift lib for it

https://github.com/apple/swift-protobuf

Protobuf is an alternate encoding to JSON that has direct support for serializing binary data.  There are client libraries for any language you might need to read the data in, or command-line tools if you want to examine the files manually.